# How to make this Flexbox responsive, it includes HTML video & text ? Plus how to hide the video controls behind the cover image?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, html5-video

Below is the code of a Flexbox that includes a HTML video and text. I tried few things but I couldn't make it responsive for both mobile and desktop.

I also want to hide the video controls behind the cover image without adding the "autoplay" option. I want the video to be played manually.

Please have a look at my code, and let me know, How can I improve it?
Thank You!

```css
.custom-btn{
  background-color: white !important;
width:300px;
margin:auto;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 15px 35px;
  
  color: black;
}
.parent {
display:flex;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 2rem 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .parent {
  padding: 2rem 16rem !important;
}
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .parent {
  padding: 2rem 18rem !important;
display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child" style="margin:auto;"><video width="360" controls poster=
"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0565/5982/9015/files/620e6ae4af9c9-fbutube-Screenshot_2022-02-17_at_9.00.40_PM_1.png?v=1645112081"><source src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0565/5982/9015/files/production_ID_4434242.mp4?v=1645111832" width="360" controls="controls"> No video support in this browser.</video></div>
<div class="child" style="margin:auto;">
<h2>Roadtrips</h2>
<a href='https://google.com'><button class="custom-btn">Visit Website</button></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: **(1)** For "responsive" through CSS, you have to use **percentages** not definite numbers. You can also try modifying the `"viewport"` entry in your `<meta>` tag setup. See [your research options](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=make+website+responsive+using+css). The first two links (from W3Schools and from DZone) might be a good starting point.

Comment: **(2)** To hide controls use Javacript. This means... Define your `<video>` tag without controls. Detect when page load is complete, then add a click listener to the video tag. The click listener runs a function that include `myVidTag.controls = true;` as well as other opts like `.play`.